# calling another function from another page

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have two htm pages, movein.htm and moveinstatementmodal.htm

on my movein.htm, i have a javascript function:

```
function doBlaBla(){

InitialLoad_Start();


}
```

the initialload_start function is both present on two htm pages. What i want to happen is when the doBlaBla function is activated, I want the movein.htm to call the initialload_start() function and I also want to call the initialload_start() function of the moveinstatementmodal.htm too. So how do i call a function from another page using javascript?

Comment: simple answer is not possible

Comment: Does at least one of the pages load in a frame (`<frame>` or `<iframe>`) within the other page? In other words: are both pages loaded at the same time in the same browser tab (or one page loads the other inside itself)?

Answer (score 0):

It's true you can't technically do it.  As a hack, you could call the page with a query string, i.e. moveinstatementmodal.htm?onload=run1.  Then, on the load of that page, you could check for the query string and run your function.

Answer (score -2):

JavaScript runs on one page at a time. So the JavaScript environment of one page is totally separate from the environment of another. It's even separate from the same page opened multiple times. Every instance has its own independent, private environment.

`<iframe>`s enable you to have more than one page in the same window, so in this case it is possible to communicate between the two pages.

Otherwise, if you want two pages to communicate with each other, you will need to use server side code to tell one page when the other has performed some action. See AJAX.

Comment: That is wrong. Simple example: two frames communicating with each other - each frame contains separate page (as frames usually do). You can find lots of examples on the web.

Comment: The OP said nothing about iframes, which is a corner case. I will update my answer to satisfy your exception.

Comment: OP did not say anything about frames, but did not say that he is not using it. However, you said things ("_the JavaScript environment of one page is totally separate from the environment of another_", "_It's even separate from the same page opened multiple times_", "_you will need to use server side code_") that make the comment field to short to give all criticism regarding that. Not only pages can communicate with each other, in many ways, but also the subsequent runs are not so separate from each other (think: cookies, local storage etc.).

Comment: @Tadeck we're talking about functions calling other functions. Reread the question. If what I said _wasn't_ true, you'd have global variables from one user clobbering the globals of another. They are **distinct** execution environments. Why don't you take offense to the other comment/answer that support my claim?

Comment: "_we're talking about functions calling other functions_": I am talking exactly about that. "_If what I said wasn't true, you'd have global variables from one user clobbering the globals of another_": no, there are different techniques that help to avoid mixed global namespaces. Are you aware of the possibility that function from one frame calls function from some other frame? In such case you do not have "_global variables from one user clobbering the globals of another_". You are not completely wrong, but your answer and comments are very misleading.